# Compare two Unordered Sheets then Highlight the Differences

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare two unordered Excel sheets. The column order is exactly the same, but the order of rows can change and values in the row can change as well.

For example, this is Sheet 1
[image]

And this is sheet 2
[image]

Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 contain same projects (except sheet 2 have one newly added project (Q41312112)). Also, although the projects are same, the $ Amount changed for some projects on sheet 2, and the orders of projects also changed on sheet 2.

Most importantly, PO/SO CANNOT serve as the “unique identifier.” As you can see, there are two rows for PO/SO M16526136, the only difference is their “Activity”, which means “PO/SO” and “Activity” together serve as the unique identifier for each project.

Is there a way to compare two unorders sheets, and highlight the true differences?
So, ideally, the result should look like this:

(Row 2 to 7 - although the order was different, these rows exist in sheet 1.
G3, G5, G7 are highlight because these projects $ Amount changed. Entire Row 8 is highlighted because row 8 itself is a new row.)

[image]

I am not even sure if this is possible in Excel, so any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You can do this with conditional formatting then. Just use SUMIFS.

Comment: I need to find exactly which cell changed and which rows are newly added. In addition, the order of rows changes everytime. So, I don't think SUMIFS can do what I need either

Comment: SUMIFS can do this - it is independent of row order. You'll need two rules though to do this with conditional formatting. The rule to color the entire row can use COUNTIFS. Let me know if that doesn't make sense and I can try to throw an answer together.

Comment: I got you now, I think I know what you mean, let me do some research

Comment: @BigBen ok...I need help. For SUMIFS, I really don't know how should I use it in this case. And for COUNTIFS, I wrote something like this for conditional formatting"=COUNTIFS($A:$A, $A:$A<>'Sheet1'!$A:$A,$E:$E,$E:$E<> 'Sheet1'!$E:$E)" . But nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two Conditional Formatting rules based on `SUMIFS` and `COUNTIFS` to do this:

**Rule 1**: To highlight **amounts** that differ:

1. Formula: `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!G:G,Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!E:E,E2)<>G2`
2. Applies to: `G2:G10000`. You could change the formula slightly and apply it to the entire column G if needed.
   [image]

**Rule 2**: To highlight **new rows**:

1. Formula: `=AND($A2<>"",COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!$E:$E,$E2)=0)`
2. Applies to: `A2:G10000`. Again you could change this as needed.
   [image]

Comment: This is awesome! But somehow these formulas are highlighting some cells they should not be highlighting, I will take a closer look, and let you know once I find out the reason

Comment: Probably because the range they are applied to isn't quite right. Pro-tip - add those formulas in separate columns on `Sheet2`. Whenever they evaluate to `TRUE`, that row should get the conditional format applied. If the `TRUE`s don't match up with highlighted rows, it means your range might be off. Note that this assumes that the combination of PO/SO and Activity is unique.